# reference a glossaries text in an acronym, sanitization and fragile commands

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

First post so be nice.

This doesn't appear to be a duplicate but maybe I am not putting in the right keywords.

I am trying to have an acronym description just be the text of a glossary item (using the `glossaries` package). This way I only have to keep the acronym expansion in one place. The problem is that the use of `\glstext` in `\newacronym` only works with `\gls` or if it isn't the first use. See below for a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Load hyperref before glossaries
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

%%% Glossary support
\usepackage[xindy,
    acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{inMyOpinion}{name={in my opinion (IMO)},
text={in my opinion},
description={This is my opinion
}}

\newacronym[]{imo}{IMO}{\protect\glstext{inMyOpinion}}


\makeglossaries

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

% Uncomment for this to fail
%\Gls{imo}, I am right.

This is \gls{imo}! 

\Gls{imo}, I am right.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]

%%% Start Glossary
\printglossary[type=main,,style=altlist]


\end{document}
```

Gives me:

[image]

If the first `\Gls{imo}` line is uncommented, then there is a error. It appears to me that the machinery that tries to capitalize the first word trips up over a fragile command because the second use works fine. I have tried turning off sanitization and applying every permutation of `\protect` I can think of with no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated on how to achieve the behavior I am after.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could of course use the code from `sample-dual.tex` in the glossaries documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy,acronym]{glossaries}

% ------------------------------------------------------------
% The code from sample-dual.tex:
% \newdualentry[main options]{label}{short}{long}{description}

\newcommand*{\newdualentry}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{main-#2}{name={#4},%
  text={#3\protect\glsadd{#2}},%
  description={#5},%
  #1
  }%
  \newacronym{#2}{#3\protect\glsadd{main-#2}}{#4}
}

\newdualentry{imo}          % label
  {IMO}                     % abbreviation
  {in my opinion}           % long form
  {This is my opinion}      % description

\makeglossaries

%%% BEGIN DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

\Gls{imo}, I am right.

This is \gls{imo}! 

\Gls{imo}, I am right.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Acronyms}]
\printglossary[type=main,style=altlist]

\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Seems that this was something that was "solved".